# In which namespace the range attribute belongs to in NUnit2.4.8

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

In which namespace the range attribute belongs to in NUnit2.4.8

Answer (score 2):

The attribute you're referring to is defined in `NUnit.Framework`, which is the default namespace for test fixtures in NUnit.

I think the reason you are confused here is that `RangeAttribute` was added in NUnit version 2.5, and so you won't find it in version 2.4.x.